# Multiple coefficient sets for least squares fitting in numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, least-squares

Is there a way to perform multiple simultaneous (but unrelated) least-squares fits with different coefficient matrices in either [`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) or [`scipy.linalg.lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html)? For example, here is a trivial linear fit that I would like to be able to do with different x-values but the same y-values. Currently, I have to write a loop:

```
x = np.arange(12.0).reshape(4, 3)
y = np.arange(12.0, step=3.0)
m = np.stack((x, np.broadcast_to(1, x.shape)), axis=0)

fit = np.stack(tuple(np.linalg.lstsq(w, y, rcond=-1)[0] for w in m), axis=-1)
```

This results in a set of fits with the same slope and different intercepts, such that `fit[n]` corresponds to coefficients `m[n]`.

Linear least squares is not a great example since it is invertible, and both functions have an option for multiple y-values. However, it serves to illustrate my point.

Ideally, I would like to extend this to any "broadcastable" combination of `a` and `b`, where `a.shape[-2] == b.shape[0]` exactly, and the last dimensions have to either match or be one (or missing). I am not really hung up on which dimension of `a` is the one representing the different matrices: it was just convenient to make it the first one to shorten the loop.

Is there a built in method in numpy or scipy to avoid the Python loop? I am very much interested in using `lstsq` rather than manually transposing, multiplying and inverting the matrices.

Comment: If you just want to get rid of the for loop, you can use `pinv` and then matrix multiplication: `fit=np.linalg.pinv(m)@y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr` together with `scipy.sparse.block_diag`. I'm just not sure it will be any faster.

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.sparse import block_diag
>>> from scipy.sparse import linalg as sprsla
>>> 
>>> x = np.random.random((3,5,4))
>>> y = np.random.random((3,5))
>>> 
>>> for A, b in zip(x, y):
...     print(np.linalg.lstsq(A, b))
... 
(array([-0.11536962,  0.22575441,  0.03597646,  0.52014899]), array([0.22232195]), 4, array([2.27188101, 0.69355384, 0.63567141, 0.21700743]))
(array([-2.36307163,  2.27693405, -1.85653264,  3.63307554]), array([0.04810252]), 4, array([2.61853881, 0.74251282, 0.38701194, 0.06751288]))
(array([-0.6817038 , -0.02537582,  0.75882223,  0.03190649]), array([0.09892803]), 4, array([2.5094637 , 0.55673403, 0.39252624, 0.18598489]))
>>> 
>>> sprsla.lsqr(block_diag(x), y.ravel())
(array([-0.11536962,  0.22575441,  0.03597646,  0.52014899, -2.36307163,
        2.27693405, -1.85653264,  3.63307554, -0.6817038 , -0.02537582,
        0.75882223,  0.03190649]), 2, 15, 0.6077437777160813, 0.6077437777160813, 6.226368324510392, 106.63227777368986, 1.3277892240815807e-14, 5.36589277249043, array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]))
```

Comment: So you're creating a set of decoupled blocks with the original matrices along the diagonal, then solving the whole thing as a giant system. This would definitely be a good idea if the matrices didn't have to be sparse. I will take a careful look at the timings.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yep, I just do not know how much time the algo wastes because nobody told it that the blocks are decoupled, in fact that there are blocks at all. Well, I guess you'll see in your timings.

Comment: I'm selecting this because it's probably the best answer I get until I start messing with the original functions myself.